# How to set looping for animation clip in script

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

When i create a animation clip in script, it seems by default it is set to not looping and i can't find where to change it.

I use

```
   Debug.Log("Input "+InputAnimation.isLooping + ", " + InputAnimation.wrapMode);
   Debug.Log("Copy " + Animation_Copy.isLooping+", "+ Animation_Copy.wrapMode);
```

to track the looping stat of my new animation clip, and it returns false from copy and true from the input.

I tried to set the wrapmode, but it seems only work with legacy clip (and it is default for both animation).

I checked the code example on this [tutorial](http://gyanendushekhar.com/2018/03/18/create-play-animation-runtime-unity-tutorial/) And i didn't find where did he set the loop mode.

here is my code.

```cs
    void CopyAnimationClip()
    {
        Animation_Copy.ClearCurves();
        for (int i = 0; i < keyframedata.Length; i++)
        {
            AnimationCurve newCurve = new AnimationCurve(keyframedata[i]);
            Animation_Copy.SetCurve(RelativePath[i], typeof(Transform), propertyName[i], newCurve);
        }
        Animator anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        AnimatorOverrideController animOverride = new AnimatorOverrideController(anim.runtimeAnimatorController);
        anim.runtimeAnimatorController = animOverride;
        animOverride["BounceAnimation"] = Animation_Copy;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see that he would have done that in the your link ... the one Animation he created on runtime doesn't loop ... the only one that loops is the one he already had created beforehand... but good question .. there seems to be no setter for this

Answer (score 3):

Use [`yourAnimation.wrapMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation-wrapMode.html)`=`[`WrapMode.Loop`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WrapMode.Loop.html)

<sup><sub>Not to be confused with the legacy variable of the same name present in [AnimationClip](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationClip-wrapMode.html).</sub></sup>

Comment: I tried to set its wrapmode, but it doesn't show any difference, and based on the API it is said to be "Only used with Legacy AnimationClip." And animation override controller can't take legacy animation clip.

Comment: @Ice.Rain note that it's the `wrapMode` in **Animation**. Not the one in `AnimationClip`.

Comment: But from what i know animation is a legacy component and not updated for a while, and animator is the newer one for playing animation and only animator (which only take animationClip) can support sprite animations.

Comment: Since there is a isLooping getter on class AnimationClip. Why is it so hard to have a setter?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you have to go to Animation Import Settings in the Inspector.

There's Import Animation and a Wrap Mode. Set that to Loop.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone who interested to this question
I found a solution (sort of) to this problem
In the animator controller, add an transition from the stat you want it to loop to itself, then the overrided animation clip will play in a loop. However i haven't find something like how to make a pingpong loop, but this already solve my problem for now.

1.Open your animator controller (open that window with animation stat graph)

2.Right click on the animation stat you want to loop

3.In the drop down menu, select make transition, then click on the animation itself.

You should see a triangle pointing to the animation stat, and that means it will play itself when it is done. So you get a looping animation. You may need some script to break the loop and redirect to somewhere else if you are making complex animations.